# Is this a valid experiment to measure the one-way speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, speed-of-light, measurements

Consider the following setup. Place a light source at point $A$ and three mirrors at point $B,C,D$ such that the light follows the path $ABCDA$ (refer diagram). Let the distance $AB=CD=2d$ and $BC=CD=d'$. Let $c_{\small PQ}$ denote the  speed of light from point $P$ to point $Q$.

[image]

Suppose $t_1$ is the time taken by the light to complete the path $ABCDA$. We have,
$$t_1=\frac{2d}{c_{\small AB}}+\frac{d'}{c_{\small BC}}+\frac{2d}{c_{\small CD}}+\frac{d'}{c_{\small DA}}\tag{1}$$

---

Now consider the same setup but this time we introduce a medium of refractive index $\mu$ which covers half the length of $AB$ (refer diagram).
[image]
Suppose $t_2$ is the time taken by the light to complete the path $ABCDA$. We have,
$$t_2=\frac{d}{c_{\small AB}}+\frac{\mu d}{c_{\small AB}}+\frac{d'}{c_{\small BC}}+\frac{2d}{c_{\small CD}}+\frac{d'}{c_{\small DA}}\tag{2}$$

---

Now consider a similar setup but this time  we introduce a medium of refractive index $\mu$ which covers half the length of $CD$ (refer diagram).
[image]
Suppose $t_3$ is the time taken by the light to complete the path $ABCDA$. We have,
$$t_3=\frac{2d}{c_{\small AB}}+\frac{d'}{c_{\small BC}}+\frac{d}{c_{\small CD}}+\frac{\mu d}{c_{\small CD}}+\frac{d'}{c_{\small DA}}\tag{3}$$

---

From equation $(1),(2)$ & $(3)$ we have,
$$t_2-t_1=\frac{(\mu-1) d}{c_{\small AB}}~~\text{and}~~t_3-t_1=\frac{(\mu-1) d}{c_{\small CD}}$$
$$\implies c_{\small AB}=\frac{(\mu-1) d}{t_2-t_1}~~\text{and}~~c_{\small CD}=c_{\small BA}=\frac{(\mu-1) d}{t_3-t_1}$$
So we are able to calculate $c_{\small AB}$ and $c_{\small BA}$. Are there any flaws in this experiment or are we able to measure the one-way speed of light using this experiment?

Doesn't $c_{\small AB}$ denote the one-way speed of light?

In the youtube video by veritasium ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k)) (5:00-6:02), Derek mentions that the speed of light need not be same in both directions. But using this experiment can't we prove or disprove that the speed of light is same in both directions?

Comment: The answer is certainly not, clearly light is making a close path (two ways).

Comment: @Mauricio I have denoted the speed of light in different directions separately (I have denoted it as $c_{\small AB}$ and $c_{\small BA}$). Can you tell me what the flaw is?

Comment: The problem with this experiment, in my opinion, is that you then assume that what a medium does to the light is exactly the same in both directions. I remember thinking hard about this, and I had a similar experiment, but found a problem with the experiment that destroyed it easily, but I can't seem to remember what exactly and Joseph's answer seems to be in the right direction. But now thinking again about this, I can also see that assuming that the refractive index and thickness of the material will result in the same outcome in the case of a different one-way speed seems fallacious. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) By that I mean that assuming that if light had a different speed, then effective length (d*$\mu$) would remain the same is complicated. I don't see how you can put both together, because the above experiment has been done and we know the phase shift is the same for both cases. Still, if I assume that the speed is different one way, then I know that the effective length will still have to be the same, so refractive index and thickness have to behave differently. However, there would be no way, unless if you could measure the true one way speed, to know if that is the case.